# Swift array does not change even thought using its reference (using inout) when passing it to a function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, func

I call a function to get data from REST api and fill array of objects with result data, I use (inout parameter) as mentioned in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267) But the array does not change

My code

```
static func getData(tab : String, inout listItems : [Item], table: UITableView) -> (){
    listItems.removeAll();
    Alamofire.request(.GET, baseURL + currencyAPI, parameters: ["tab":tab]).responseArray { (response: Response<[Item], NSError>) in

        let items = response.result.value
        if let items = items {
            listItems.appendContentsOf(items)
            table.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

and function call

```
APIManager.getData("syp", listItems: &listItems, table: sypTable)
```

Update: when I put API request inside viewDidLoad function it works correctly

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //APIManager.getData("syp", listItems: &listItems, table: sypTable)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, baseURL + currencyAPI, parameters: ["tab":"syp"]).responseArray { (response: Response<[Item], NSError>) in

        let items = response.result.value
        if let items = items {
            self.listItems = items
            self.sypTable.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure? When are you looking wether or not `listItems` have changed? seems like the method is asynchronous.

Comment: The code you've posted looks correct to me. The issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint  at (table.reloadData()), I can see that (items) have 5 items while (listItems) is empty

Comment: Regardless, as the network request will complete asynchronously, you can't use the contents of `listItems` immediately after the call to `getData`. A better approach is to pass a closure to `getData` that does what you need with the new data and have this invoked by the closure passed to `request`